# Returning Asynchronous function then assigning a value swift

Tags: swift, asynchronous, async-await, google-maps-sdk-ios

I'm attempting to return the value of an array and then assign its value to a variable, however when doing so, it returns a blank array. I'm assuming this is due to my lack of knowledge on how to use async in swift so was hoping someone could show me how to do so for this segment of code:

```
func assignWeights(){
        var weightedList = [GMUWeightedLatLng]()
        getCoords { coords in
            self.coords = coords
            for coord in coords {
                let lat = Double(coords.location.latitude)!
                let long = Double(coords.location.longitude)!
                let coordinates = GMUWeightedLatLng(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat,long), intensity: 2.0)
                weightedList.append(coordinates)
            }
            print(weightedList) //Array prints contents
        }
        print(weightedList) //Empty array
        heatmapLayer.weightedData = weightedList //Sets to empty array [] as this is ran before getCoords{
    }
```

Comment: Where do you assign any value to `heatmapLayer.weightedData`? It's not visible from your code snippet. But generally, you want to assign it within the closure, where the value is received (where you put the "Array prints contents" comment).

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I tried assigning it where you described and it did not seem to actually set the value of heatmapLayer.weightedData unfortunately. I believe it's because getCoords has a completion handler causing it to call asynchronously!

Comment: yes you are correct, `...I believe it's because getCoords has a completion handler causing it to call asynchronously`. Try moving `heatmapLayer.weightedData = weightedList` just after the `for coord in coords {...}`. That is, inside the `getCoords { coords in ...}` closure.

Comment: Tom, are you asking us how to fix this incorrect completion handler code or how to properly implement it with async-await? The old completion handler pattern is completely different paradigm than the async-await of the new Swift concurrency system.

Comment: Note that, if `getCoords { coords in ... }` closure is on a background thread (most likely),
 and you need to update `heatmapLayer.weightedData` to change the user interface, you need to
 update it on the main thread, like this `DispatchQueue.main.async { self.heatmapLayer.weightedData = weightedList }` inside the closure.